# Keyframes in Dope Sheet Less Than Second

Tags: animation

I would like to know if it's possible to save bone structure how the figure should be between seconds. That green line only locks to seconds like 1, 2, 3 and so on.. but the character moves the head faster, how can I save it between the seconds if it's even possible.

[image]

Is it possible to do at 3.5 or even more accurate, like 3.12 or something like that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First off you are viewing frames, not seconds. (You can switch to view seconds, but that is a different matter). Yes you can keyframe sub frame, just turn off the auto snap.